I have two different statements for the t test and the single tail test
I want to check whether the values of a group (ct2 are greater than the values of ct1). To do this, I have applied a T test which has the following results.
t = 5.194, df = 1.6778, p-value = 0.05009
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 per cent confidence interval:
 -0.001132843 1.961132843
sample estimates:
mean of x   mean of y 
     2.10        1.12 

I have specified the significance level (alpha) of 0.05. Since the result p-value = 0.05009 is above 0.05, according to the t test a change in the means is not to be classified as significant.
However, I have tested this sample in a single tail test and as you can see in the figure, the t test is greater than the critical value! This would indicate that the null hypothesis is rejected and there is a change. How can the contradictory statement arise?


You performed a two tailed test to get a $p$-value of $0.05009$ but looked at one tail for the critical value.
Using R:

A one-tailed $p$-value
  > pt(5.194, df=1.6778, lower.tail = FALSE)
  [1] 0.025047


A two-tailed $p$-value
  > 2 * pt(5.194, df=1.6778, lower.tail = FALSE)
  [1] 0.050094


A one-tailed critical value
  > qt(0.95, df=1.6778)
  [1] 3.340753


A two-tailed critical value
  > qt(0.975, df=1.6778)
 [1] 5.200078




Hi thank you so much how do i perform a one tail t test in r?

@Weiss If you are using t.test(x, y = NULL, alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"), mu = 0, paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, ...) then you may want to state alternative="less" if your null hypothesis is $\mathbb E[X] \ge \mathbb E[Y]$ and your alternative hypothesis is $\mathbb E[X] \lt \mathbb E[Y]$. The default is alternative="two.sided"

?t.test or help("t.test") or this link will get you to the manual page

Henry gave you results from R.
More intuitively, the two tests are answering different questions, so they get different answers. The two tailed test asks

Are the two means significantly different?

The one tailed test asks:

Is mean 2 significantly greater than mean 1?


(or maybe the other way round, your question doesn't specify which direction).
You may say "how can one mean be greater than the other but not different?" and the answer is that it can't. But look at the adverb "significantly".
In the one tailed test you are focusing on one tail. So you can find more things. BUT if the answer was in the other direction, then you couldn't find it at all, no matter how big it was.
Imagine you are told that, somewhere in a house, in either the living room or dining room, there is a winning lottery ticket for MegaMillions. You have one hour to find it. So you search both rooms. You have a small chance of finding it.
Now suppose they tell you it is in the dining room. You have a better chance of finding it in one hour. Unless, of course, they are lying to you and it's in the living room, in which case you have no chance at all.
Getting back to statistics, unless you have very strong reason to do a one tail test, it's usually right to do two tail.
Also, it's good to look at effect size and not just p value, and not to have some rigid cutoff for significance.

There is no contradiction. The rejection region for your two-sided $t$-test is given by
$$
\left(-\infty, t_{0.05 /2}(1.6778)\right] \cup \left[-t_{0.05 /2}(1.6778), \infty\right) \approx \left(-\infty, -5.2\right] \cup \left[5.2, \infty\right),
$$
where $t_{0.05 /2}(1.6778)$ is the $0.05 / 2 = 0.025$ quantile of Student's $t$ distribution with $1.6778$ degrees of freedom.
